# Fact table updatable/deletable rows

Tags: database, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, star-schema, fact-table

AFAIK, the best practices say that you should never updated fact table rows, at least for transaction and periodic snapshot grains. While reading about [Fact Table Surrogate Key](https://www.kimballgroup.com/2006/07/design-tip-81-fact-table-surrogate-key/), found a notion of updates:

> Certain ETL techniques for updating fact rows are only feasible if a
>   surrogate key is assigned to the fact rows. Specifically, one
>   technique for loading updates to fact rows is to insert the rows to be
>   updated as new rows, then to delete the original rows as a second step
>   as a single transaction. The advantages of this technique from an ETL
>   perspective are improved load performance, improved recovery
>   capability and improved audit capabilities. The surrogate key for the
>   fact table rows is required as multiple identical primary keys will
>   often exist for the old and new versions of the updated fact rows
>   between the time of the insert of the updated row and the delete of
>   the old row.

*Did Bob Becker mean updates/deletes from fact table? Is it a common practice?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time to time you may need to *update* a fact table, simple from the reason that wrong data were loaded.

Not sure how a surrogate key can help here
 - you must find the rows to be changed based on the natural keys.

But yes, an `INSERT` and `DELETE` (possible only *logical* delete setting a cancellation flag) could be
 prefered to a simple  `UPDATE` basically from auditibility and recovery reasons. Again I'm not sure how this can affect performance.

Above all, a best practice of 2006 need not be a current best practice - nowadays
 a non-trivial *fact tables* typically do not have a *primary key* as a unique index makes the rolling partition window concept harder. (If required, the uniqueness is checked in ETL process).